# Redirect images to a page with .htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to know if it possible to set up a redirect in the htaccess file so that if an other website directly links to an image on my site, instead of the image opening in a browser window on its own, the page that the image is hosted on is displayed.

This page has the same name as the image i.e. if the image the other site is linking to is

www.mysite.com/imagename.jpg

then I want it to redirect to a page called

www.mysite.com/imagename/

Comment: I updated my answer. I made a mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17753981/1932751

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/main/[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}/([\.]+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ /$1/ [R=301]
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working. Also the images are all in directories like http://mysite.com/wp-content/main/2013_07/imagename.jpg

Comment: But it's not what you said in your ask post. And to what url do you want to redirect these images ?

Comment: Sorry, im not sure how to edit my origional post.  I have a wordpress blog and I would like all image links on other sites that follow the format http://mysite.com/wp-content/main/2013_07/imagename.jpg to redirect to mysite.com/imagename/

Comment: What do you want to say with "that's not working for me" ? Do you get an error page ? or the redirection is not etablished ?

Comment: it does nothing. the pictures still load in the browser and do not redirect

Comment: can you send a real url ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteRule ^wp-content/main/.+/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ /$1/ [R]
```

Comment: What if the image file is in a directory such as http://mysite.com/wp-content/main/2013_07/imagename.jpg

Comment: is that a general structure example? or the explicit structure?

Comment: Its a wordpress blog.  the structure remains the same except for the date part which changes each month and year.

Comment: do you want to retain the structure? i.e. mysite.com/wp-content/main/2013_07/imagename.jpg ->  mysite.com/wp-content/main/2013_07/imagename/

Comment: this http://randompics.net/wp-content/main/2013_04/uE4d7Ce.jpg should redirect to http://randompics.net/uE4d7Ce/